# What is the best practice to turn input File Browse Button into a Dropzone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, input, dropzone.js

I'm new to [dropzone](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#installation), and I want to turn my browse button into my dropzone that accepts files.

[image]

This is my form now.

```
@extends('layouts.be.master')
@section('content')

<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.8.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<div class="card-body card-padding">
    <div class="row">


        {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal dropzone', 'role' =>'form', 'url'=>'portfolio/store','files' => true)) !!}

        <div class="col-sm-12">

            {{-- Name --}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" value="{{Request::old('name')}}"  value="" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </div>

            {{-- Type --}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="type" class="form-control">
                        @foreach($portfolioTypes as $item)
                        <option value="{{ $item }}">{{ $item }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            {{-- Tags --}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tags</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">

                </div>

                <input id="tags" name="tag">
            </div>

            {{-- URL --}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="url" class="col-sm-2 control-label">URL</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input name="url" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="URL">
                </div>
            </div>


            {{-- URL --}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="url" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Images</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 ">

                    <input id="images" name="images[]" type="file" multiple>

                </div>
            </div>

            {{-- Description --}}
            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">

                    <textarea name="description" rows="20" cols="80" id="description">
                    </textarea>
                    <script>
                        CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );
                        CKEDITOR.config.height = 500;
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="/portfolio"> Cancel </a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Create</button>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>


        {!!Form::close()!!}


    </div>
</div>

@stop

@section('custom-scripts')

{{-- Tags --}}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.tag-editor.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.caret.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.tag-editor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dropzone.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#tags').tagEditor({

        autocomplete: {
            delay: 0,
            position: { collision: 'flip' },
            source: [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $skillList).'"' ?>]
        },
        forceLowercase: false,
        delimiter: ',', /* space and comma */
        placeholder: 'Enter tags ...',
        initialTags: ['HTML','CSS','Javascript','jQuery','Bash']

    });

    $("#images").dropzone();

</script>
@stop
```

This is my result

[image]

The documentation suggested to add the `class"dropzone"` to the form element, but that if I my entire form only have file upload, but I have other inputs as well.

Right now, my browse button works perfectly (100% tested), and I don't want to break that functionality at all.
I just want to improve the look of it, added the ability to drop files, and submit those files as soon as form submit.

## How would one deal with that ?

---

## Update

I tried what @Kunal suggested

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone= {
    url: 'portfolio/store',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    maxFiles: 5,
    maxFilesize: 1,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    init: function() {
        dzClosure = this; // Makes sure that 'this' is understood inside the functions below.

        // for Dropzone to process the queue (instead of default form behavior):
        document.getElementById("submit-all").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            dzClosure.processQueue();
        });

        //send all the form data along with the files:
        this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
            formData.append("name", jQuery("input[name ='name']").val());
            formData.append("name", jQuery("select[name ='type']").val());
            formData.append("name", jQuery("input[name ='tag']").val());
            formData.append("name", jQuery("input[name ='url']").val());
            formData.append("name", jQuery("textarea[name ='description']").val());
        });
    }
}
```

I don't see anything submit to my back end, and also it seems to submit 2 times, because I see 2 records created.

[image]

Comment: Care to explain why you downvote my post ? Did I do sth wrong ? 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the dropzone.js with other `inputs` in your `form` by just changing some setting in the dropzone.js. And they are as follows

1: Create a normal form (don't forget the method and enctype args since this is not handled by dropzone anymore).

2: Put a div inside with the class="dropzone" (that's how Dropzone attaches to it) and id="yourDropzoneName" (used to change the options).

3: Set Dropzone's options, to set the url where the form and files will be posted, deactivate autoProcessQueue (so it only happens when user presses 'submit') and allow multiple uploads (if you need it).

4: Set the init function to use Dropzone instead of the default behavior when the submit button is clicked.

5: Still in the init function, use the "sendingmultiple" event handler to send the form data along wih the files.

HTML

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id ="firstname" name ="firstname" />
    <input type="text" id ="lastname" name ="lastname" />
    <div class="dropzone" id="myDropzone"></div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit-all"> upload </button>
</form>
```

Dropzone.js

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone= {
    url: 'upload.php',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    maxFiles: 5,
    maxFilesize: 1,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    init: function() {
        dzClosure = this; // Makes sure that 'this' is understood inside the functions below.

        // for Dropzone to process the queue (instead of default form behavior):
        document.getElementById("submit-all").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            dzClosure.processQueue();
        });

        //send all the form data along with the files:
        this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
            formData.append("firstname", jQuery("#firstname").val());
            formData.append("lastname", jQuery("#lastname").val());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this submit to backend as soon as file uploaded or only after use clicked on submit ?

Comment: In third step as mentioned by deactivating the ` autoProcessQueue` both the working as submitting to backend and uploading will be done on your permissions (i.e when submit is clicked).

Comment: I checked Network Tab, I see POST request trigger as soon as file uploaded. !! Is it expected ?

Comment: No,it's not expected.

Comment: Please check your conditions for posting.

Comment: I saw you sent all inputs accept the file one. How do I sent the file too ?

Comment: I figured it out, I had to do this. `formData.append("images[]", dzClosure.files);`

Comment: It is caused by the plugins which blocks the script but don't worry about that because i have used it myself to.This plugin will not cause this error.

Comment: I figure it out too. `formData.append("_token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/9CjAqj3.png - why do I see progress bar on top of images ?

Comment: It is a part of plugin if you want you can make the following changes in its css.